# while running my react native code in xcode version 14.3 i am facing issue

Tags: xcode, react-native, version, apple-m1

No such module 'AcuantImagePreparation

tried
deleting node_module
deleting pod and pod.lock
and again installing it but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

i think in your assets there are same content like images that's why it is happened.

Comment: i have fixed the issue. some issue was in my project setup only

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: May your current react-native version?